# hadoop datanode dies after few seconds

Tags: hadoop

I installed hadoop-2.2.0 version on vmware and when it starts, it shows all the processes working, but after some time datanode gets killed. So, I checked the logs and I found this:

```
2014-01-21 04:36:00,325 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2014-01-21 04:36:21,034 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.net.UnknownHostException: ubuntu: ubuntu
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1402)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getLocalHostName(SecurityUtil.java:227)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.login(SecurityUtil.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1640)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1665)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1837)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1858)
2014-01-21 04:36:21,107 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2014-01-21 04:36:21,114 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at java.net.UnknownHostException: ubuntu: ubuntu
************************************************************/
```

Comment: I think the problem is with localhost... check  `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1402) at `

Comment: please, specify in your own answer (if another answer did not solve this problem) how you solved it and accept your own answer, for future readers.

Comment: I changed the etc/hosts file as in the first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `/etc/hosts` file.
Make sure it is configured correctly. My `/etc/hosts` file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.0.1     master  mypcname
192.168.0.18    slave1
192.168.0.12    slave2
192.168.0.17    slave3
```

for master and

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.0.1     master
192.168.0.18    slave1  slave1pcname
192.168.0.12    slave2
192.168.0.17    slave3
```

for slave1.

Comment: then, you can click on the white tick next to my answer, to set it as accepted, so that others will know what to do if they have the same problem. I'm glad that I helped.

Comment: thanks for ur support i have been trying to do this from 2 days it worked finally